# When does OnItemActivatedListener.onItemActivated gets triggered in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-jetpack, multipleselection

The documentation for [`OnItemActivatedListener.onItemActivated`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/OnItemActivatedListener#onItemActivated(androidx.recyclerview.selection.ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails%3CK%3E,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) says that this method is

> Called when an item is "activated". An item is activated, for example, when no selection exists and the user taps an item with her finger, or double clicks an item with a pointing device like a Mouse.

But, when no selection exists and user taps an item with her(/his) finger, the item does not get activated. As I know, when there is no selection, you have to long press an item for activating it, and only the subsequent items can be activated just by tap. (By activation, here, I mean item-selection. [Sorry that Android messed up with their terminology](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setActivated(boolean)).)

So, I wanted to clarify if this method is called when the item is just-tapped or activated by long-press.

Answer (score 0):

Long-press doesn't work, but it gets triggered when an item is being tapped.
And it doesn't even add the item to the selection, unless explicitly adding it.